# c# double screen app, how to change frame of the mainwindow from second window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have an app that works in two screens, the second screen is a settings panel. From the settings panel i need to refresh the content of the frame in the main window. I'm using this code:

```
  MainWindow winFirst= new MainWindow();
        var primaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

        if (primaryScreen != null)
        {

            winFirst._mainFrame.Source = new Uri("DynamicSource.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            winFirst.Show();
        }
```

with this code i can load in main window what i need by pressing a button in second window. But this code load a new MainWindow class every time i launch it...I think it's not the best approch, maybe i will encounter some memory related problem. So if this is a problematic approch how i cand do to access the frame of the current mainWindow and change it without reinit ?

```
Application curApp = Application.Current;
Window mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow;
```

i have also try this code but in this way i can't find in mainWnd the _mainframe element.

Comment: use `var mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow as MainWindow` to cast the main window so you can access it - btw the whole 'two screen' story is completely irrelevant: your question would be exactly the same, but shorter, if you'd have the two windows running on one screen..

Comment: it works,thank you. If you rewrite it as an answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main window can always be accessed by Application.Current, but it is returned as a Window. However since you know what it should be, you can just cast it:

```
var mainWin = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
Debug.Assert( mainWin != null ); //sanity check
//do things with mainWin
```